# Highcharts {Pie} - Remove slice pieces out onclick

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

How can I remove slice out of pie chart pieces?

> **[`Online Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/7fvmtnm8/)**

**Reference**

[image]

Comment: you have ' sliced: true' parameter in your data point, simply delete it and your chart will look like you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this animation with [plotOptions.pie.slicedOffset](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.slicedOffset) property.

So, just by setting `slicedOffset: 0`, you will get desired behavior.

```
series: [{
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: false,
          }
        },
        name: 'Brands',
        slicedOffset: 0,
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
          name: 'IE',
          y: 56.33
        }, {
          name: 'Chrome',
          y: 24.03,
          sliced: true,
          selected: true
        }, {
          name: 'Firefox',
          y: 10.38
        },  {
          name: 'Others',
          y: 0.2
        }]
      }]
```

Live example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fvmtnm8/1/).